# The spaces $L^p$ with $0<p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Assume that there exists a constant $ M> 0$  such that   $/\hat{u}/  >M$ .

Is the following inequality true?

$\left \|  \hat{u}\right \|_{L^{p}}  $ $\leq $ $\left \|  \hat{u}\right \|_{L^{2}}  $
with $ 0<p<1$ .

Thanks.

Comment: the title says $1 < p < 1$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please give more details: $L^p$ over what set? Is $\hat u$ the Fourier transform? What have you done so far? Where does this problem come from?